# Java8 Stream: using if/else condition inside a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've been using the Java 8 Streams for a while. I came across a situation where I need to use if/else condition while iterating a stream. I have a list like this. I want to create an object of MetricForAccount class for each item of the list

```
private List<String> metricNames = ImmutableList.of("ReadConsumedCapacity",
            "WriteConsumedCapacity", "SuccessfulRequestLatency", "ReturnedItemCount");
```

```
List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();


metricNames.stream()
                .map(metricName -> new MetricForAccount().withAccountId(subscriberId)
                        .withMetricName(metricName)
                        .withStat(SUM)
                        .withPeriod(PERIOD)
                        .withNamespace(AWS_DYNAMO_DB_NAMESPACE)
                        .withRegion(region)
                        .withDimensions(dimensions)
                        .withRange(range))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want add different item to the dimensions list based on the metric name. I am not sure how can I use if else inside the map. Any suggestion?

Comment: How would you write what you're trying to do without streams?

Comment: If you write your lambda `metricName -> { ... }`, then you can put as many lines of normal source code as you like in the body.

Comment: May be my question is not clear. I want to add different item in the dimensions list, ".withDimensions(dimensions)".. rest everything will be same

Comment: @LouisWasserman I understand what you are saying. I want an optimized way to change the dimensions list in the above case

Comment: Do you know how to do this when streams aren't involved?

Comment: Just to be sure, does your `dimensions` list contain multiple `Dimension`  objects per `MetricForAccount` object?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply extend the callback and use and if/else statement inside this callback.
Like this:

```java
List<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();

metricNames.stream()
    .map(metricName - > {
        if (matches(metricName)) return new MetricForAccount().withAccountId(subscriberId)
            .withMetricName(metricName)
            .withStat(SUM)
            .withPeriod(PERIOD)
            .withNamespace(AWS_DYNAMO_DB_NAMESPACE)
            .withRegion(region)
            .withDimensions(dimensions)
            .withRange(range);
        else return new MetricForAccount().withAccountId(subscriberId)
            .withMetricName(metricName)
            .withStat(SUM)
            .withPeriod(PERIOD)
            .withNamespace(AWS_DYNAMO_DB_NAMESPACE)
            .withRegion(region)
            .withDimensions(otherDimensions)
            .withRange(range);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: May be my question is not clear. I want to add different item in the dimensions list, ".withDimensions(dimensions)".. rest everything will be same

Comment: Yes I undestood what you meant or I at least think that I did, I edited my answer, please have a look at that one.

Comment: If that would have been the case, why not use a ternary operator as `return new MetricForAccount().withAccountId(subscriberId)
            .withMetricName(metricName)
            .withStat(SUM)
            .withPeriod(PERIOD)
            .withNamespace(AWS_DYNAMO_DB_NAMESPACE)
            .withRegion(region)
            .withDimensions(matches(metricName) ? dimensions : otherDimensions)
            .withRange(range);`